# Angular - how to make a simple carousel for li tags

Tags: angular

I want to make a carousel of `li` tags.

I have images in an array:

```
export class ProducersComponent implements OnInit {

  //Producer icons
  items = [
    '../../../assets/producers/1.png', 
    '../../../assets/producers/2.png', 
    '../../../assets/producers/3.png', 
    '../../../assets/producers/4.jpg', 
    '../../../assets/producers/5.png', 
    '../../../assets/producers/6.png', 
    '../../../assets/producers/7.jpg', 
    '../../../assets/producers/8.png'
  ];

  //Holds current window width
  innerWidth;

  //Holds index number of first and last icon displayed on screen
  firstItemToPrint;
  lastItemToPrint;

  //Updates the window width
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    //Changes the number of icons displayed on small and wider screens
    if (this.innerWidth < 600) {
      this.firstItemToPrint = 0;
      this.lastItemToPrint = 4
    } else {
      this.firstItemToPrint = 0;
      this.lastItemToPrint = 8
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onResize(event);
    // Changes the icons on slider
    setInterval(()=>{
      let itemToMove = this.items.shift();
      this.items.push(itemToMove);
    },3000)
  }
}
```

And for start I made only a simple interval that changes the order.
But in this solution the elements just apper 0/1.
How can I mage it look like carousel?

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | slice:firstItemToPrint:lastItemToPrint">
      <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + item + ')'}"  class="producers">

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean : 'apper 0/1' ?

Comment: slice must be firstItemToPrint:lastItemToPrint+1

Comment: I mean that it skips and doesn't not animate.